# Script Not Working For Datepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to do a Start/End date for my datepicker and had the script with me which I have found in [Bootstrap-Datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/). I have followed closely the documentation but the script only trigger `.datepicker`, which turns the `<input>` into a datepicker but the behavior is not what I want. Some help from the community please?

Script:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var nowTemp = new Date();
            var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

            var checkin = $('#dateFrom').datepicker({
                onRender: function (date) {
                    return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
                }
            }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
                    var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
                    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
                    checkout.setValue(newDate);
                }
                checkin.hide();
                $('#dateTo')[0].focus();
            }).data('datepicker');
            var checkout = $('#dateTo').datepicker({
                onRender: function (date) {
                    return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
                }
            }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                checkout.hide();
            }).data('datepicker');
        });
    </script>
```

This is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="dateFrom" class="col-md-2 control-label">Date From:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="input-group date">
                                <input type="text" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" class="form-control col-sm-2" required placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"/>
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="dateTo" class="col-md-2 control-label">Date To:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="input-group date">
                                <input type="text"  id="dateTo" name="dateTo" class="form-control col-sm-2" required placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? What exactly do you mean by "the rest stops running"?

Comment: @saadq The datepicker is able to show up on the webpage but the way I want the datepicker to behave is not working as what I would like to be.

Comment: You should be a bit more descriptive. What is the expected behavior and what is the actual behavior?

Comment: @saadq My bad. The expected behavior I would like is when user choose a start date from today onward and end date should not allow user to choose previous date that were picked on start date. Currently, the behavior is the start date and end date shows the datepicker but the function I mentioned above is not working.

Comment: From the documentation it doesn't appear possible to create restrictions using this tool. All it allows for is error messages if you choose wrong, which isn't necessarily the best feedback to the user. Is using for example jQuery UI Datepicker (https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) an option? I can provide sample code for that which sets a minimum date for the start, and prevents the end date from being before the start.

Comment: @MiikaL. Yes, JQuery UI is an option. I hope to move on quickly as I am stucked for days trying to figure out getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you said using jQuery UI Datepicker (https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) is an option, so here is some sample code for that.

Note the current date has to be written for the start value. Write also a default value for the end date if you want. The dates should be written in the format that you specify for the datepicker.

```
<input class="input-small" style="cursor: pointer;" type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate" readonly value="13.11.2015" />
<input class="input-small" style="cursor: pointer;" type="text" id="endDate" name="endDate" readonly />

var $startDate = $('input[name="startDate"]');
$startDate.datepicker({
    minDate: $startDate.val(),
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    constrainInput: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    showOn: "both",
    showWeek: true,
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
    },
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $endDate.datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
}).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
        $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
    }
});

var $endDate = $('input[name="endDate"]');
$endDate.datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    constrainInput: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    showOn: "both",
    showWeek: true,
    minDate: $startDate.val(),
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
    }
}).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
        $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
    }
});
```

If you want, I can also modify this sample a bit to include a button that makes it look a bit more Bootstrappy (2.X version compatible)

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker you use is a bit old (last update 2013...).

Try to use this fork : https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker 
and check [the doc](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

This is one work for date range and many other things... (and as it's a fork, it's more compatible with your actual code)